# How to add a title and substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a list of names as per the following format
**"Mr."+first name initial+last name+"."**
There is only one table for this

```
salesperson (f_name, l_name)
```

What i have been trying is;

```
SELECT 'Mr.' ||' ' || SUBSTRING(f_name,1,1) || ' ' || l_name ||’.’||
FROM salesperson;
```

It works without the **substring** or **left**, but not if I include them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat` instead of `||` operator to concatenate strings in MySQL. As you have it, it would be interpreted as logical `OR` condition, hence you get the error.

```
SELECT CONCAT('Mr.',' ',SUBSTRING(f_name,1,1),' ',l_name,'.')
FROM salesperson;
```

Oracle solution

```
SELECT 'Mr.'||' '||SUBSTR(f_name,1,1)||' '||l_name||'.'
FROM salesperson;
```

Comment: It gives "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments"

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Your question says MySQL.

Comment: Apologies, Im using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It is better practice anyways to grab the name data in full and then format it in the view part of your application with languages that are more suited to string manipulation. This also makes your code more reusable.

That being said use this

```
    SELECT CONCAT("Mr. ",SUBSTRING( f_name, 1, 1 ) ," ",l_name,".") FROM salesperson
```